# Почему эта строка в golang не преобразуется в число?

Tags: golang

```
func Delete_exam(UserId int,ExamId string){     //я передаю ExamId строкой и хочу перевести в int
    log.Println(ExamId ) //отображается число в кавычках , т.е. string тип
    var Exam_id_int int
    if Exam_id, err := strconv.Atoi(string(ExamId)); err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("Exam_id=%d, type: %T\n", Exam_id_int , Exam_id_int )
    }
//.......
}
```

Я на 100% уверен, что внутри текста число, а оно попадает в исключение, т.е. не может преобразовать. В то же время, если я принудительно задам ExamId="777" , то здесь число распознается и будет всё ок.
Может в ExamId есть какие-то символы ещё, из за чего он не хочет перевестись в int? Что-то бьюсь головой об стену- не могу понять

Comment: Вывод на печать того, что не может быть преобразовано пробовали?

Comment: Спасибо, вывел - оказалось ExamId ="\"1\"" .Я по-дыбильному позаписывал, а потом выяснял- в чём дело....

Comment: Отладчик - очень полезная штука!

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

```
func Delete_exam(UserId int,ExamId string){ 
    log.Println(ExamId ) 
    var Exam_id_int int
    if Exam_id, err := strconv.Atoi(string(ExamId)); err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("Exam_id=%d, type: %T\n", Exam_id_int , Exam_id_int )
    }else{log.Println("Error-",err.Error())} //Показало ошибку
}
```

Спасибо  Владимиру Мартьянову. Вывел просто ошибку и посмотрел в чём дело.
Оказалось, у меня ExamId было "\"1\"" , поэтому в консоле выводилось и нормально, но не преобразовывалось. Вообщем нашёл место,где ExamId сохранялось, поставил без \"  и всё заработало